# A limit involving the Thue–Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, limits, conjectures

*(it is a follow-up on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2720878/19661))*

Let's define $t_n$ by the recurrence
$$t_0 = 1, \quad t_n = (-1)^n \, t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}.\tag1$$
It is easy to see that $|t_n|=1$, and the signs follow the same pattern as  the [Thue–Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence):
$$1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,-1,\,1,\,1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,1,\,-1,\,1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,...\tag2$$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891648/19661) for an example of a non-recursive formula for $t_n$).

Now, let:
$$\mathcal{L}(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}t_k\,k^z.\tag3$$
I conjecture that the following propositions hold:

> $\color{gray}{\text{(a)}}$ The limit $\mathcal{L}(z)$ exists for all $z\in\mathbb C$.
>
> $\color{gray}{\text{(b)}}$ $\mathcal{L}(z)$ is an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) of $z$.
>
> $\color{gray}{\text{(c)}}$ $\mathcal{L}(z)=0$ if <s>and only if</s> $z\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Can we prove these conjectures? Can we find a different representation of $\mathcal{L}(z)$? Does this function have any interesting properties?

*Update:* The "if" part of the conjecture $\color{gray}{\text{(c)}}$ is [certainly true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163403/19661). I am now pretty sure the "only if" part fails at some points on the imaginary axis (e.g. near $z\approx i\,4.53236...$; is it exactly $i\,\pi/\ln2$?). I am still wondering if there are any zeros except positive integers and off the imaginary axis.

*Update:* I found a very relevant and interesting paper (preprint) by Giedrius Alkauskas, *Dirichlet series associated with Thue–Morse sequence*[$^{[1]}$](http://uosis.mif.vu.lt/%7Ealkauskas/MP3/thue_morse.pdf)[$\!^{[2]}$](https://www.pdf-archive.com/2018/04/13/thue-morse/thue-morse.pdf) (be aware that the author claims[$^{[3]}$](https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/%7Ealkauskas/math/index.html) some results in it may be incorrect).

---

Here is my attempt to plot the function for a range of real arguments:
[image: the function plot]

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581072/223829) a form i figured in thue-morse sequence, I hope it's relevant for your quest.

Comment: A bit of plotting with Mathematica suggests that $z_k=(2k+1)\pi i/\ln 2, k=0,1,2,\ldots,$ might all be zeros. I truncated the sum at $k=255$, so I won't bet any money on it, but so far that is suggested.

Comment: Perhaps, a more natural function to ask about would be $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}t_k\,\left(2k+1\right)^z$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov It's just $(2^z-1)\mathcal{L}(z)$ - what's so special about it? BTW, the statement on zeros mentioned by Jyrki Lahtonen is proven _correctly_ in the paper you've found (worth noting in the text of the question, nothing more).

Comment: Right, there is not a significant difference. I just meant that if we start summation from $k=0$ (because we do not have to care about $0^z$ for negative $z$), then there is exactly $2^n$ terms.

Comment: Another related paper: http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem92-93/allouche.pdf

Comment: You can also look at J.-P. Allouche, H. Cohen, Dirichlet series and curious infinite products, Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 17 (1985), 531–538.
best wishes
jpa

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is still an open problem to determine whether those are *all* the zeros.

Answer (score 5):

I claim that, for non-integers $z$ with $\Re z > 0$, the following holds:
$$ \mathcal{L}(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)} \int_0^\infty t^{-z-1} \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1-e^{-2^k t})\,dt.$$
Here's my way to get it. Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b$ be positive real numbers, and $z$ be a non-integer complex number with $\Re z < n$. Then
$$ \int_0^\infty t^{-z-1} e^{-bt} \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-e^{-a_k t})\,dt = \Gamma(-z) \sum_{c\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{c_1+\ldots+c_n}(b+c_1 a_1+\ldots+c_n a_n)^z.$$
This may be proven by induction on $n$ (here's the reason of introducing $b$). Now take $a_k=2^{k-1}$:
$$ \int_0^\infty t^{-z-1} e^{-bt} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-e^{-2^k t})\,dt = \Gamma(-z) \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} t_k (b+k)^z$$
(where $t_k$ is the sequence in the question), and it remains to take $n\to\infty$ and $b \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! The representation you found seems correct. It is basically the Mellin transform of the infinite product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform).

Comment: Might be related: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610525